# Before Evolution was proposed by Charles Darwin, what were the leading secular theories to explain how life developed?

Tags: evolution, history

Outside of evolution, what were the leading scientific schools of thought that Charles Darwin contented with when he published his evolution theory as way of natural selection in 1859?

Comment: Hello. I think you'll get the answer to your question on this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_evolutionary_thought). There is probably too much to say in a post. I vote to close because it is too broad. Please let me know if you think the wiki post can't answer your question.

Comment: Saltationism maybe?

Comment: Darwin stood on the shoulders of giants, most notably Alfred Russel Wallace

Comment: @Remi.b I did not know that all theories before Darwinism were listed under the umbrella of evolution. For example the theory of Spontaneous generation, did that ever have any mainstream acceptance within the scientific community?

Comment: @GabrielFair absolutely. And it makes total intuitional sense - you take a piece of meat, put it outside, and within a relatively short period of time it has maggots on it. Same thing with hay - cut and dry it in the field, put it on the wagon and bring it back to the barn, and before you know it there are mice in it, which certainly weren't in there before. It feels completely logical. Besides, fresh hay doesn't produce maggots, and rotting meat doesn't produce mice, so the "seeds" of those animals must be within the originating substance.

Comment: Of course, not *all* things behave this way - we know that ducks come from duck eggs, and puppies come from a bitch, and so forth, but when you don't have the knowledge or creativity to set up a completely controlled experiment, it all seems to make a great deal of sense. Remember, the average level of education back then was *much* lower than today, and most "scientists" (they called themselves natural philosophers) were self-taught.

Comment: Most of the evolutionary thoughts presented in the wiki article I linked were build at a time where the word science (and the scientific methodology) didn't even exist, so it is a bit complicated to group those opinions into any category. [Lamarckism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamarckism) was clearly an important mode of thinking at the time of Darwin, there are a number of works that kinda anticipated the process of natural selection before Darwin. You can have a look at this history on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_evolutionary_thought#Early_19th_century).

Comment: Voted to re-open as it is a valid question with an interesting answer. Broad yes, but philosophical questions such as this one are fundamental to science. Darwin is seen as the founding father of evolution, but some major players pre-dating him set the stage for his appraised evolution theory.

Comment: related: [*How was the resemblance between apes and humans explained in pre-Darwinian biology?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/24697/3624)

Comment: Oh wow, Thanks @fileunderwater, for sharing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were many (more or less) non-theological theories of how life had developed before Darwin, starting at the ancient greeks. Many theories included [spontaneous generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_generation) but also aspects of modification by descent of existing species (i.e. evolutionary change), but most were not that well developed and complete thought. However, one of the more complete evolutionary theories that pre-dated Darwin was [**Lamarckism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamarckism), which claimed that individuals pass on traits that they have acquired during their life time. So the basic idea was that individuals respond and adapt to the environmental conditions they experience, and that these traits are then transferred to their offspring. This is one example of a non-theological theory that pre-dated Darwin, but I cannot really say if it was the leading one. I do know that Lamarck's ideas were relatively ignored during his own lifetime.

Darwin included some aspects of these ideas in his "*Origin of Species*", but challanged Lamarckism when it came to the main processes of evolution. A weak interpretation of Lamarckism has actually seen a revival after the discovery that epigenetics can be transferred from parents to offspring, see e.g. [Heard & Martienssen (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867414002864) and [Szyf (2014)](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v17/n1/abs/nn.3603.html).

Comment: Wow this was really fascinating, I did not know this.

Comment: @fileunderwater - shouldn't this question be re-opened? It is a valid question and your answer is great (+1'd fyi)

Comment: @AliceD I think the close reason is somewhat valid. You could write a book on this topic. On the other hand, a couple of answers that highlight different theories could probably provide a nice overview for somebody new to evolution.

Comment: Autochthonous generation proposed that different species were formed independently and through natural processes, "by chance". Scottish philosopher David Hume believed that if the universe had no beginning, then it became likely that somewhere (e.g. Earth) the unlikely event of particles accidentally arranging into orderly entities (e.g. life) could happen.

Comment: Deism was also invoked to explain biology during the Enlightenment. Deists believed in a god, but largely rejected religion and worship. So it was a kind of "secular theism", where intelligent design is inferred, but the identity of the creator is left unexplained. Much before that, some Greek philosophers ascribed to a "demiurge", a god-like being who arose from primordial chaos and then proceeded to order what was around it to create the world.